# program runs but returns no response when reading an xml file

Tags: python, xml, beautifulsoup, lxml

Here is the code to my program:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


with open('wiki_articles.xml', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    data = f.read()


bs_data = BeautifulSoup(data, "xml")

bs_title = bs_data.find_all('title')

print(bs_title)
```

The program runs but doesn't return anything. It quits only when I stop it.
I have tried other tags and the problem still persists.
The xml file is around 220 Mb and my computer is capable of running this program.

Comment: That's a big XML file!  How long did you let it run before killing it?  Note: keep your eye on process memory usage using "top" or Task Manager or somesuch.  Parsing this beast may eat up RAM.

Comment: You are correct. It was eating up the RAM. Do you have any suggestions on how to work with it?

Comment: Check out this page: https://codefaster.substack.com/p/mastering-jq-xml-and-any-other-data -- it suggests a recipe for stream-converting the XML to JSON, then using the magical tool "jq" to pull out fields (then optionally converting back to XML).  What makes it good for this task is that these tools work on streams, not giant blocks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please make correction the parser  name `lxml` instead of `xml`.

```
bs_data = BeautifulSoup(data, "lxml")
```

Comment: thanks... It worked!